# Selection Sort not sorting Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am working on a selection sort in Java.  It will prompt a user to enter in 10 names and then sort them alphabetically.  It is sorting some of them but not completely and cannot figure out why it is sorting some values and not others.  I believe I have implemented the sort and swap correctly but I feel as though I am missing something.  Any help is appreciated as always.

```
import java.util.*;

public class sortingProgram {

    static String studentName[] = new String[10];
    static int i;
    static Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void enterNames() {
        for (i = 0; i < studentName.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a student name: ");
            studentName[i] = scnr.nextLine();
        }
    }

    public static void sortNames(String sortArray[]) {
        int smallindex;
        for (int i = 0; i < sortArray.length; i++) {
            smallindex = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < sortArray.length; j++) {
                if (sortArray[j].compareTo(sortArray[smallindex]) < 0) {
                    smallindex = j;
                    if (smallindex != i)
                        swap(sortArray, smallindex, i);
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortArray));
    }

    public static void swap(Object a[], int i1, int j1) {
        Object temp = a[i1];
        a[i1] = a[j1];
        a[j1] = temp;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        enterNames();
        sortNames(studentName);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're supposed to finish the inner loop before you swap, not swap in the middle of the inner loop. Also, making `i` static is a code smell.

Comment: A debugger is a great tool to find out what is going on in your program.

Comment: Your swap should be at end of first loop. Also iterate your first loop till <sortArray.length -1

Answer (score 0):

You are doing your `swap` too early. You need to wait until the smallest has been determined before swapping. You are swapping whenever you detect a smaller one.

```
public static void sortNames(String sortArray[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sortArray.length; i++) {
        int smallindex = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < sortArray.length; j++) {
            if (sortArray[j].compareTo(sortArray[smallindex]) < 0) {
                smallindex = j;
                // Move this.
                //if (smallindex != i)
                //    swap(sortArray, smallindex, i);
            }
        }
        // To here.
        if (smallindex != i)
            swap(sortArray, smallindex, i);
    }
}

public static void swap(Object a[], int i1, int j1) {
    Object temp = a[i1];
    a[i1] = a[j1];
    a[j1] = temp;
}


private void test() {
    String[] names = {"C", "B", "A", "9"};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
    sortNames(names);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use below changes in your program.

```
import java.util.*;

    public class SortingProgram {

        static String studentName[] = new String[10];
        static int i;
        static Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        public static void enterNames() {
            for (i = 0; i < studentName.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a student name: ");
                studentName[i] = scnr.nextLine();
            }
        }

        public static void sortNames(String sortArray[]) {
            int smallindex;
            for (int i = 0; i < sortArray.length; i++) {
                smallindex = i;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < sortArray.length; j++) {
                    if (sortArray[j].compareTo(sortArray[smallindex]) < 0) {
                        smallindex = j;
                        //if (smallindex != i) No need here
                        //swap(sortArray, smallindex, i);
                    }
                }
                //place your swaping code here
                if (smallindex != i)
                      swap(sortArray, smallindex, i);
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortArray));
        }

        public static void swap(Object a[], int i1, int j1) {
            Object temp = a[i1];
            a[i1] = a[j1];
            a[j1] = temp;
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            enterNames();
            sortNames(studentName);
        }
    }
```

after making these changes your program works. your code not works properly because you perform swap early.